# non-nominal type X does not support explicit initialization

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, swift4

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong with generics in swift.

I created this sample playground

```
import UIKit

public protocol MainControllerToModelInterface : class {
    func addGoal()
    init()
}

public protocol MainViewControllerInterface : class {
    associatedtype MODELVIEW
    var modelView: MODELVIEW? {get set}

    init(modelView: MODELVIEW)
}

public class MainViewController<M> : UIViewController, MainViewControllerInterface where M : MainControllerToModelInterface {
    public weak var modelView: M?

    required public init(modelView: M) {
        self.modelView = modelView
        super.init(nibName: String(describing: MainViewController.self), bundle: Bundle.main)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

public class Other<C, M> : NSObject where C : MainViewControllerInterface, C : UIViewController, M : MainControllerToModelInterface, C.MODELVIEW == M {
    var c : C?

    override init() {
        let m = M()
        self.c = C(modelView: m)
        super.init()
    }
}
```

the line `self.c = C(modelView: m)` gives me this error `non-nominal type 'C' does not support explicit initialization`

From [this other stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46086345/swift-generics-non-nominal-type-does-not-support-explicit-initialization) question I see that this error in older Xcode versions means

`cannot invoke initializer for type '%type' with an argument list of type '...' expected an argument list of type '...'`

But in the playground above what is the compiler missing?

I'm on swift4/xcode9.

**Update**

After following the suggestion `Use C.init(modelView: m) rather than C(modelView: m)` the error changes in:

`No 'C.Type.init' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '_?'`

Than @vini-app suggested to remove the UIViewController to make it works. By I still don't understand why the compiler is not happy when UIViewController is there. Is it not enough to know that C has that valid init method?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You just need to use `init` explicitly whenever you're initializing a generic parameter rather than a "real" type:

```
self.c = C.init(modelView: m)
```

Comment: Thanks, than I get `No 'C.Type.init' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '_?'`

Comment: it's not working Swift 4.1. I have to remove UIViewController constrained. but I need this constraint. any idea how to fix?

Comment: add the required statement before your init definition and this works

Answer (score 3):

Use `C.init(modelView: m)` rather than `C(modelView: m)`. That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, than I get `No 'C.Type.init' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '_?'`

Comment: On my main project this actually solves the issue. But giving the check to the other answer because it was first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Please check :

In your code you are doing like this `C : MainViewControllerInterface, C : UIViewController`.

It is treating `C` as ViewController, then there is no `init` in ViewController like `init(modelView: M)` thats why its throwing error

```
public class Other<C, M> : NSObject where C : MainViewControllerInterface, M : MainControllerToModelInterface, C.MODELVIEW == M {
    var c : C?

    override init() {
        let m = M()
        self.c = C(modelView: m)
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but C is `C : MainViewControllerInterface`. That protocol defines the initializer i’m using there.

Comment: After deleting ViewController, its working. Please check my code.

Comment: Yes, but still, it's like the thing it's that I need that. you say that `It is treating C as ViewController, then there is no init in ViewController like init(modelView: M) thats why its throwing error` but this doesn't make sense to me. C is also adopting `MainViewControllerInterface`, so why is not enough for the compiler?

Comment: Is because UIViewController is a class and not a protocol?