# Non-nominal type 'User' does not support explicit initialization

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift4

I a struct model named User.. with the following code

```
struct User {
    let userId: Double
}

extension User {
    init(json: JSON) {
        self.userId = json["userId"].double!
    }
}
```

And have normal class with generic like the following

```
class LoginTask<User>: Operation {

    var userName: String
    var password: String

    init(username: String, password: String) {
        self.userName = username
        self.password = password
    }

    var request: Request {
        return UserRequests.login(username: self.userName, password: self.password)
    }

    func exeute(in dispatcher: Dispatcher, completed: (User) -> Void) {
        do {
            do {
                try dispatcher.execute(request: self.request, completion: { (response, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        let user = User(json: response)

                    }
                })
            } catch {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Operation is a protocol is having associatedtype named Output

now on line

```
let user = User(json: response)
```

it gives error

> Non-nominal type 'User' does not support explicit initialization

I tried to make User.Type .. but may be I don't fully understand the concept or the error.

Comment: try using explicit init: `let user = User.init(json: response)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [non-nominal type X does not support explicit initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458657/non-nominal-type-x-does-not-support-explicit-initialization)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ tried it but it gives (Type 'User' has no member 'init')

Comment: see Jeremy's answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `User` in your class is not the same as the `User` type you created. It's just a placeholder for any type. You could replace the word `User` in your class definition with anything e.g. `T` or `Apple` and it would still be the same definition.

The compiler knows nothing about what`init` methods `User` in your class has, hence the error. To make it work properly, you must constrain the type parameter. This is usually done by making it conform to a protocol e.g.

```
protocol JSONInitable
{
    init(json: JSON)
}

struct User: JSONInitable { ... }
struct Group: JSONInitable { ... }

class LoginTask<PrincipalType: JSONInitable> 
{ 
    ....

    func foo() 
    {
       let user = PrincipalType(json: response)
    }
}
```

In the above, the LoginTask can be used with both `User` and `Group` but not any arbitrary type that doesn't conform to the protocol.

Alternatively, if the class will always use the `User` type, it doesn't need to be generic.

Comment: Perfect solution in my honest opinion :)