# can't call custom init method on a generic protocol constrained to a concrete type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to write a CollectionDataAdapter as Follow:

```
public protocol InitializableCell {
    associatedtype T

    init(item: T)
}
```

---

```
public typealias ACCollectionNodeCellAction = (_ collectionNode: ASCollectionNode, _ indexPath: IndexPath, _ object: Any) -> Void

open class ASCollectionNodeAdapter<Provider: CollectionDataProvider, Cell: ASCellNode>:
    NSObject,
    ASCollectionDataSource,
    ASCollectionDelegate
    where Cell: InitializableCell, Provider.T == Cell.T
{
    // MARK: - Delegates
    public var didSelectCell: ACCollectionNodeCellAction?

    // MARK: - Private Properties
    let provider: Provider
    let collectionNode: ASCollectionNode

    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    init(collectionNode: ASCollectionNode, provider: Provider) {
        self.collectionNode = collectionNode
        self.provider = provider
        super.init()
        setUp()
    }

    func setUp() {
        collectionNode.dataSource = self
        collectionNode.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - ASCollectionDataSource

    public func numberOfSections(in collectionNode: ASCollectionNode) -> Int {
        return provider.numberOfSections()
    }

    public func collectionNode(_ collectionNode: ASCollectionNode, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return provider.numberOfItems(in: section)
    }

    public func collectionNode(_ collectionNode: ASCollectionNode, nodeBlockForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> ASCellNodeBlock {
        return { [weak self] () -> ASCellNode in

            guard let `self` = self, let item = self.provider.item(at: indexPath) else {
                return ASCellNode()
            }
            return Cell.init(item: item)


        }
    }

    // MARK: - ASCollectionDelegate
}
```

problem is I can't init Cell that is of Type `ASCellNode` and conforms To `InitializableCell` saying:

> Argument labels '(item:)' do not match any available overloads

if I call init like this: `Cell(item: item)` compiler complains:

> Non-nominal type 'Cell' does not support explicit initialization

how is it happening? because Cell is already conforming to the `InitializableCell` protocol

Comment: Looks like you should specify `Cell.T` in `where` statement. Like `Cell.T: NSObject`

Comment: How are you calling the method?  What is the definition of the type are you passing for `Cell`?

Comment: @Avi item is an struct type model. the scenario I have implemented is some how like this question, there is a sample playground: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458657/non-nominal-type-x-does-not-support-explicit-initialization